# Ayuda con este problema para mover una imagen en PHP y CSS

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

Estoy aprendiendo lenguaje de programación php con base de datos y MySQL pero no puedo mover una imagen hacia la derecha y 3 palabras hacia la izquierda (están invertidas, osea imagen izquierda y palabras derecha) y ya no tengo ni idea de que hacer ¿Pueden ayudarme? Logre cambiar de lugar las palabras pero al momento de intentarlo con la imagen, las palabras se mueven junto a la imagen, quisiera saber que etiqueta usar para hacer esta operación y que no hacer al momento de colocarlo. HTML:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Experto HTML</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="encabezado">   
    <div class="centrar">

        <img src="img/logo.png">

        <ul class="opciones">

            <li class="opcion">Nosotros</li>
            <li class="opcion">Servicios</li>
            <li class="opcion">Contactanos</li>
        </ul>

    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
*{
margin: 0; /*margen 0*/     
padding: 0; /*espaciado 0*/
}
#encabezado{
    width: 100%; /*anchura*/
    background-color: #000;

}
.centrar{
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

.opciones{
    color: #fff;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;   
}
.opcion{
    float: left;
    padding: 30px 30px;
    border-left: #fff solid 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

He modificado tu `css` y he quitado de la clase `opciones` el modificador `position` y con eso la imagen se fue a la derecha, quedando de la siguiente forma:

```
*{
margin: 0; /*margen 0*/     
padding: 0; /*espaciado 0*/
}
#encabezado{
    width: 100%; /*anchura*/
    background-color: #000;

}
.centrar{
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

.opciones{
    color: #fff;
    list-style-type: none;
    /* position: absolute; */
    top: 0;
    right: 0;   
}
.opcion{
    float: left;
    padding: 30px 30px;
    border-left: #fff solid 1px;
}
```

Comment: Agradezco bastante tu ayuda, ahora podre seguir con mi tarea.

Comment: Que bien que te ayudo, puedes indicarla como respuesta correcta si gustas.